# Prove $λ^∗(U) < ε$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $ε > 0$. Prove that there exists an open set $U ⊆ R$ which contains all rational points such that $λ^∗(U) < ε$.

Where lambda star is the outer Lebesgue measure.

We know $λ^∗(U) \geq 0$, and we know $\mathbb Q \subseteq U$, so $λ^∗(\mathbb Q) \leq λ^∗(U) $ by general properties of outer Lebesgue measure. Since $\mathbb Q$ is countable, $λ^∗(\mathbb Q) =0$.

That's all I can think of. Please help.

Comment: Enumerate $\Bbb{Q}= \{ q_n \}_{n \ge 1}$. Then $U= \bigcup_{n \ge 1} (q_n - \varepsilon 3^{-n} , q_n + \varepsilon 3^{-n} )$ satisfies your condition.

Comment: where did you get the number 3 from?

Comment: Well, I needed any positive real number $a$ such that $\sum_{n \ge 1} a^{-n} < 0.5$: I took $3$ (actually a good choice would be anything bigger than $3$).